# Populating DropDownList based on another DropDownList (Cascading Drop Down)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, c#-4.0

I am having trouble getting the functionality we want in our `Create View` in our ASP.NET MVC application.

We have got two DropDownLists in our `Create` View.

One is a selection of categories and the second should be populated with items based on the `id` value of the first category selected. (They have a FK relationship).

Have you guys encountered any similar situation and can you give me some advice or a hint on how I can tackle this problem best?

- Should I create some specified ActionResult method for this?
- Or should I go with a `static` method in the Repository / Controller?

All help is more than appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for a [Cascading Drop Down](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/730953/Cascading-Dropdown-List-With-MVC-LINQ-to-SQL-and-A).

Comment: Link is broken. Here's the new working one: http://www.michaeljbaird.com/post/2009/04/13/aspnet-mvc-and-jquery-cascading-dropdown-list.aspx

Comment: Second link is broken

Comment: @Tony_Henrich I've linked a code project one, hopefully this time it will live.

Answer (score 3):

Just to clarify what `NicklLarsen` said

> If you want them to update on the page without having to reload after every selection of the first drop down list, you will want to use cascading drop downs

Cascading drop downs is short for making an AJAX call to another action method with the selected value of the first drop down list. The action method would take that value, use it to look up the corresponding information based on that value, and return a JSON/XML format of the list of items. Using javascript, you would then update the second drop down list with items.